Socket Error: OS Error: [WinError 10048] Only 1 usage of each socket address is normally permitted - port is confirmed unused
Thanks in advance!
I am following along with Edureka's Python full Course[2024] youtube video. Windows 10; PyCharm 2024.3.1.1(Professional Edition); python 3.13.1-amd64.
I cannot get past sockets and pickle modules. When I run server in command prompt, it works. When I then run client in command prompt, it gives this error:
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UserName\PycharmProjects\Socket Programming\CLIENT2.py", line 6, in <module>
    s.bind((socket.gethostname(),2133)) 
    ~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permiitted

I have cleared the port 50 times in the command prompt using netstat -ano | findstr :2133
and taskkill /pid [] /F where [] is the pid #
and confirming using netstat -ano | findstr :2133
Server: File Name: SERVER2 ; cmd from project folder to run py SERVER2.py
import socket
import pickle

a=10
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(),2133)) #binding tuple
s.listen(5)
while True:
    clt,addr = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection to {addr}established")

    m={1:"CLIENT", 2:"SERVER"}
    mymsg = pickle.dumps(m) #the message we want to print later
    mymsg = bytes(f'{len(mymsg):<{a}}',"utf-8") + mymsg
    clt.send(mymsg)

Client: File Name: CLIENT2 ; cmd from project folder py CLIENT2.py
import socket
import pickle

a=10
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(),2133))  #binding tuple

while True:
    complete_info = b''  #message being received is in bytes so specify b with an empty string
    rec_msg = True
    while True:
        mymsg = s.recv(16)
        if rec_msg:
            print(f"The length of message = {mymsg[:a]}")
            x = int(mymsg[:a])
            rec_msg = False
        complete_info += mymsg
        if len(complete_info)-a == x:
            print("received the complete info")
            print(complete_info[a:])
            m=pickle.loads(complete_info[a:])
            print(m)
            rec_msg = True
            complete_info=b''
        print(complete_info)


The error is correct.  You only use bind in the server.  The client uses connect.  You're trying to serve twice.

This worked! I've spent hours on a copy/paste error. Thanks Tim!
